# Avoid code duplication between two functions, but one returns in the middle of the code

Tags: c++, c++11, code-duplication

Lets say i have two functions inside a class:

```
vector<int> getAllPossibleNumbers() {
    vector<int> nums;
    for (int i=0; i < MAX; i++)
        if (isAPossibleNumber(i))
            nums.push_back(i);
    return nums;
}

bool hasAtLeastOnePossibleNumber() {
    for (int i=0; i < MAX; ++i)
        if (isAPossibleNumber(i))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I could rewrite the second function as

```
bool hasAtLeastOnePossibleNumber() {
    return getAllPossibleNumbers().size() > 0;
}
```

But it's obvious, especially with a very high MAX number, how the first is much more efficent.

So, how can I avoid code duplication of this kind?

I would prefer a general solution, that can work with more complicated functions and can compile with C++11.

Comment: I don't think this is a case where you can avoid the "duplication". The functions do different things, even if they use the same container.  What you could do is use `std::copy_if`, and `std::any_of` in the function bodies.

Comment: Seems like a "getFirstPossibleNumber" function might help. And at that point you might as well write an iterator over all possible numbers and use that in your functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to move most of the logic into a third function with a callback to the outer functions which gives the numbers. The result of the callback can be used to determine whether to continue the loop:

```
template <typename Callback>
void checkNumbers(Callback callback)
{
    for (int i=0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (isAPossibleNumber(i))
        {
            if (!callback(i))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::vector<int> getAllPossibleNumbers() {
    std::vector<int> nums;
    checkNumbers([&](int i){ nums.push_back(i); return true; });
    return nums;
}

bool hasAtLeastOnePossibleNumber() {
    bool result = false;
    checkNumbers([&](int i){ result = true; return false; });
    return result;
}
```

The extra function should be optimised away by modern compilers.

Comment: Nice, but having said that, probably not worth it. The original implementation is way clearer. The only reason to do that would be for some kind of improve in re-usability other than just these two functions.

Comment: @AdrielJr yes, definitely not worth it but the OP said the real use case was more complex. Given there's only 2 lines of code in the original functions there isn't much you can do to make it simpler

Comment: Thank you! I probably simplified too much the question, but this is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldnt bother too much to refactor the code, because the duplciation is not that drastic. The two functions really do different things. However, if you write a function that only returns a single `int`:

```
const int MAX = 100;
bool isAPossibleNumber(int i){ return true;}

int getNextPossibleNumber(int start=0,int stop = MAX) {
    for (int i=0; i < stop; i++) {
        if (isAPossibleNumber(i)) return i;
    }
    return stop;
}
```

Then one of the functions will be simple and short

```
bool hasAtLeastOnePossibleNumber() {
    return getNextPossibleNumber(0,MAX) != MAX;
}
```

While the other becomes a little more verbose

```
std::vector<int> getAllPossibleNumbers() {
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int start = 0;
    while (start < MAX) {
        auto i = getNextPossibleNumber(start);
        if (i != MAX) nums.push_back(i);
        start = i+1;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Note that in total this is more code, so its a trade-off. If you don't need `getNextPossibleNumber` also elsewhere I would probably leave your code as is.

---

Also note that while this reduces code duplication a little, it does not reduce the amount of work that needs to be done when you do for example:

```
if (hasPossibleNumber()) {
    auto vec = getAllPossibleNumbers();
}
```

In the worst case the only possible number is `MAX-1` and both functions will iterate the whole range. Instead of letting both functions do the work maybe you are better off at caching the result and reusing it when either of the function is called again.

Comment: I thought about such function, the problem is that in my real case it would be very verbose, difficult to write and easy to mess. Basically it works with  2d coordinates around a point that must be search with some criteria and checked with a different criteria. My fault, I simplified too much in my question. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *actually* have any code duplication. It just looks like you do, because you've used index based for loops to implement different algorithms. If you write loops like this everywhere, it's going to look like you have repeated code.

What you should do is use the appropriate algorithms

```
vector<int> getAllPossibleNumbers() 
{
    vector<int> nums;
    std::ranges::copy_if(std::views::iota(0, MAX), 
                         std::back_inserter(nums),
                         isAPossibleNumber);
    return nums;
}

bool hasAtLeastOnePossibleNumber() 
{
    return std::ranges::any_of(std::views::iota(0, MAX),
                               isAPossibleNumber);    
}
```

And now there's nothing really to deduplicate.

*This is C++20 code, but you can do pretty much the same thing in older revisions.

Comment: I simplified too much the question, in my real case I can't use those algorithms. Thank you though.